# Convert Recursive jQuery For each loop into JavaScript for VBA Script Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, vba, scriptcontrol

I'm trying to use the following script to iterate through a nested JSON object.  It works fine in html, however, I'm calling it from a Excel VBA ScriptControl object.  When I do, it returns an "undefined" error for the "$"

I'm assuming it's because the VBA ScriptControl does not allow for jQuery (is that true?)

So... Can some help in converting the "$.each()" parts below into javascript?

Code:

```
function jsonFunction() {
    var jsonObj = {
        Item1: 'This is a test',
        Item2: { Value1: '100', Value2: '200' },
        Item3: { Value1: '101', Value2: '201' },
    };

    var result = '';

    $.each(jsonObj, jsonLoop);

    function jsonLoop(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            $.each(value, jsonLoop);
        } else {
            result += key + ' : ' + value + ', ';
        }
    } 
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create your own `each` function

```
function each(obj, cb) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        cb(key, obj[key]);
    }
}

function jsonFunction() {
    var jsonObj = {
        Item1: 'This is a test',
        Item2: { Value1: '100', Value2: '200' },
        Item3: { Value1: '101', Value2: '201' },
    };

    var result = '';

    each(jsonObj, jsonLoop);

    function jsonLoop(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            each(value, jsonLoop);
        } else {
            result += key + ' : ' + value + ', ';
        }
    } 
    return result;
}
```